# Valgrind on macOS Ventura 13.0

Tags: valgrind, macos-ventura

I'm having troubles installing Valgrind on the macOS Ventura (13.0) through the Homebrew. In the terminal I have tried following.

```
$ brew install valgrind
```

After Homebrew's autoupdate, I got the following message:

```
valgrind: Linux is required for this software.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

Is there a way I can install Valgrind?

I wanted to run Valgrind for debugging c

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Valgrind is not supported on macOS 13.0.

The last officially supported version is 10.13. There is no support at all for Apple silicon.

Some support for macOS versions after 10.13 is available here https://github.com/LouisBrunner/valgrind-macos

None of the Valgrind developers is actively working on Valgrind macOS. Apple makes zero contributions. I do occasionally make some changes, but that's just at the level of checking that the old code still builds.

Your best bet, if your software is portable to other OSes, is to test it on FreeBSD or Linux.

Comment: thanks! this is helpful. Maybe I will explore creating a docker with a compatible Linux image.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the built in MacOS command `leaks`:

`$ leaks <your program>`

For usage details see:

`$ man leaks`